# Visual Studio online build failing with 0 warnings and 0 errors

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am just setting up a basic build with a very bare bones WebApi App, and I am getting a failed build, but without any errors or warnings... how can i figure out what is going wrong?

```
Project "d:\a\1\s\My.Project.Api.sln" (1) is building "d:\a\1\s\My.Project.Api\My.Project.Api.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
 _CleanRecordFileWrites:
   Creating directory "obj\Release\".
 Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\My.Project.Api\My.Project.Api.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
 Done Building Project "d:\a\1\s\My.Project.Api.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

 Build FAILED.
     0 Warning(s)
     0 Error(s)

 Time Elapsed 00:00:00.15
 ##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Even any way I can get a useful log or error message would be great!

Edit:
I added `/v:diag` for the build arguments for verbose logging, but it really isn't seeming to help.

Comment: Could you provide a clear screenshot/screenshots of your Build pipeline? It would help in tracing where the things went wrong

Comment: Set system.debug to true and queue build, then post the detail build log here.

Answer (score 2):

Before Visual Studio build task, you should use `nuget restore` to download packages your project is referring.

So please add a **Nuget task** before Visual Studio build task. Detail setting for NuGet task as below:

**Command:** `restore`

**Path to solution, packages.config, or project.json:** `**/*.sln` or select relative path for `My.Project.Api.sln`

`Feeds to use:` Feeds in my NuGet.config

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition, there is a variable called `system.debug` which is set to `false`. Change this to `true` at the template or at the time of triggering and you will get the debug lines written by the build tasks. Inspect the debug lines and you might find the issue.